# NSPredicate to filter Getting No Results

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nspredicate

I am trying to predicate the array
with this
    -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
    {

```
if(text.length == 0)
{
    isFiltered = FALSE;
}
else
{
    isFiltered = true;
    filteredListCustomersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[customersArray count]];

    [filteredListCustomersArray removeAllObjects];
    NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.text contains[c] %@",text];
    filteredListCustomersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[customersArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate]];
    searchText=text;
}
[customerstableView reloadData];
}
```

I am Unable to get the results.
Please help me in this,

```
<__NSArrayM 0x608000458480>(
{
    FLD =     (
                {
            NAME = BPCNUM;
            TYPE = Char;
            text = ACTR001;
        },
                {
            NAME = BPCNAM;
            TYPE = Char;
            text = "Regal Enterprises";
        },
                {
            NAME = BPCSHO;
            TYPE = Char;
            text = Regal;
        }
    );
    NUM = 1;
},
{
    FLD =     (
                {
            NAME = BPCNUM;
            TYPE = Char;
            text = ACTR003;
        },
                {
            NAME = BPCNAM;
            TYPE = Char;
            text = "Mace Supplies";
        },
                {
            NAME = BPCSHO;
            TYPE = Char;
            text = Mace;
        }
    );
    NUM = 2;
})
```

Here I want text = "Regal Enterprises" for predicate

Comment: What is crash log edit your question and add that crash log

Comment: Try like `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"text contains[c] %@",text];` and you need to show the crash log

Comment: Once check with the array, I didn't get the results NIRAV

Comment: If you want the solution you need to show the crash log not the array

Comment: If you have a crash, show the crash log. Also, avoid showing images of your code/data, copy/paste the entries of your array instead.

Comment: Show me the **CRASH LOG**

Comment: Here is no crash with this approach but getting results nill

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your predicate:

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" ANY FLD.text contains[c] %@", text];
filteredListCustomersArray = [[customersArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate] copy];
```

Comment: Thanks Bro It's Working well. You saves my time

Comment: Lal Krishna here i need to predicate only index 1 text ("Regal Enterprises","Mace Supplies") how can i do that

Comment: use for-in & get value by FLD[1]

Comment: that means predicated by the FLD[1] text?

Comment: no. `for(FLDModel *FLD in arrayName) { [customArray addObject: FLD[1]]; }` something like this

Comment: Thanks brother
    for (NSDictionary *obj in customersArray){
            NSString *sTemp = [[[obj valueForKey:@"FLD"]objectAtIndex:1]valueForKey:@"text"];
            NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            
            if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            {
                [filteredListCustomersArray addObject:obj];
            }
    }
i did like this and got it.